# The code isn't printing anything, and I can't find the problem

Tags: java, object

The goal of this is to print out the size of the blob when given a set of coordinates within a 10 x 10 matrix. It's written in java and the point of the exercise was to use recursion to find each of the 1's in the blob. (Any 1's that are connected to the original coordinate by going up, down, left, or right.

```
Example:
The Blob
    0010010010
    0100100101
    1001001010
    0011110101
    0111101010
    1001010100
    0010101101
    0101010010
    1010100100
    0101001000
The Coordinates
    1 1
    2 3
    5 7
The Output
1
10
3



      import java.util.*;
        
        public class BlobsRunner
        {   
            public static void main(String[] args)
            {
                //test the Blob class to make sure
            //it works as intended
            Blobs bloop = new Blobs(10, 10);
            //call both constructors
            Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Row: ");
            int r = reader.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Colum: ");
            int c = reader.nextInt();
            bloop.recur(r, c);
            bloop.getBlobCount();
            //print the newly instantiated Blob
            bloop.toString();
            //call methods - print out the size of the blob
            //bloop.getBlobCount();  
        }   
    }

//next file

import java.util.*;

public class Blobs
{
    private int[][] mat;   //grid of 1s and 0s
    private int count;
    private int[][] visited;
    public Blobs( int rows, int cols )
    {
        //set count to 0
        count = 0; 
        //point mat at new mat size rows X cols 
        mat = new int[rows][cols];          
        //loop through mat
        for(int a = 0; a < rows; a ++)
        {
            for(int b = 0; b< cols; b++)
            {
                mat[a][b] = (int)Math.random();
            }
        }
           //fill in mat with 1s and 0s 
           //use Math.random()
        visited = new int[rows][cols];
    }

    public Blobs( int rows, int cols, String s )//what does s mean?
    {
        //set count to 0
        count = 0;
        //point mat at new mat size rows X cols 
        mat = new int[rows][cols];  
        for(int a = 0; a < rows; a ++)
        {
            for(int b = 0; b< cols; b++)
            {
                mat[a][b] = (int)Math.random();
            }
        }
        visited = new int[rows][cols];
        //loop through mat
           //load in the 1s and 0s from s
    
    }
    
    public void recur(int r, int c)
    {
        //add a base case
        if(mat[r][c]==0)
        {
            //return;
        }
        if(visited[r][c] == 5)//figure out, make sure it doesn't count if it does
        {
            //return;
        }
        visited[r][c] = 5;
            //mark current pos as visited   
        count++;
            //increase count by 1   
            //add in 4 recursive calls
        //UP
        if(mat[r+1][c] == 1 && visited[r+1][c] != 5)
        {
            recur(r+1, c);
        }
        //DOWN
        if(mat[r-1][c] == 1 && visited[r-1][c] != 5)
        {
            recur(r-1,c);
        }
        //LEFT
        if(mat[r][c-1] == 1 && visited[r][c-1] != 5)
        {
            recur(r,c-1);
        }
        //RIGHT
        if(mat[r][c+1] == 1 && visited[r][c+1] != 5)
        {
            recur(r,c+1);
        }
    }

    public int getBlobCount()
    {
        //return count
        return 0;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        //you will need nested loops
        //you will need a local string variable
        for(int a = 0; a < mat.length; a++)
        {
            for(int b = 0; b < mat[a].length; b++)
            {
                System.out.print(mat[a][b]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Math.random()` function returns double values between 0 to 1 so when you try to convert it  to `(int)` it becomes 0. So all of your matrix is 0. And since you are doing nothing at `recur()` function its print 10x10 0 matrix.

Try adding `import java.util.Random;` then `Random r = new Random();` and when you assign random numbers `mat[a][b] = r.nextInt(2);`

Answer (score 0):

As *@Fatih Aslan* noted, `Math.random()` produces a double between 0.0 and 1.0, not including 1.0. When parsed to an int, Java will always produce the value 0.

If you do not want to use the `java.util.Random` library you can multiply the value you are obtaining from `Math.random()` by the difference between the highest and lowest random numbers you would like to generate, plus 1. If you want your lowest possible random number to be greater than 0, add that number to the output of `Math.random()`.

For example, `(int)(2 + (Math.random() * 9))` will produce random integers from 2 to 10 including 2 and 10.